# How to delete selected record from tableview using asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

This is the my view code edit button working successfully. i want to delete particular selected record. when your click delete icon model popup will open then it will ask yes or no. if user click yes i need to call action method. how to call that method?  when i try to run parameter null its coming to action method.

```
  <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User ID</th>
                        <th>User Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var gt in Model.UserList)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@gt.UserId</td>
                            <td>@gt.UserName</td>
                            <td>@gt.Email</td>
                            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("getUserDetailById", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "Edit-User", AllowCache = true, InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith,LoadingElementId="resultLoadingDiv" }))
                            {
                                @Html.Hidden("userId", @gt.UserId)

                                <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit/View"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit/View" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>
                            }    
                                <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"  data-userid="@gt.UserId" data-title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Script:

```
        debugger;
    $('#mytable').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var userId = $(this).data('UserId');
   if (bootbox.confirm('Do you want to delete this item?', function (result) 
    {
    if (result == true) {
        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Admin/deleteUser/" + userId,
    success: function (result) {
      },
     complete: function () {

  },
    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
  }
  });
  }
  else {
        return;
    }
   }));
  })
```

My Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult deleteUser(string userId)
    {
        _objuser = new UserService();
        var  status = true;


        var gt = _objuser.deleteUserDetail(userId);


        return new JsonResult { Data = status, JsonRequestBehavior = 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
```

may be the problem with controller action only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to download and use [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) for consistent alert boxes in your app and its easy to use too:

```
bootbox.confirm({
message: "This is a confirm with custom button text and color! Do you like it?",
buttons: {
    confirm: {
        label: 'Yes',
        className: 'btn-success'
    },
    cancel: {
        label: 'No',
        className: 'btn-danger'
    }
},
callback: function (result) {
 if(result === true){
     //YOUR DELETE ACTION METHOD AJAX CALL HERE
  }
 }
});
```

**Attach delete event like this to your table delete buttons**

```
$('#yourTableId').on('click', '.delete', function () {           
        var userId= $(this).data('userid');
        if (bootbox.confirm('Do you want to delete this item?', function (result) {
            if (result == true) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Admin/deleteUser", 
                    data:JSON.stringify({userId:userId})
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                       
                    success: function (result) {
                    },
                    complete: function () {

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                return;
            }
        }));
```

**Change Delete button in view as below:**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" data-userid="@gt.UserId" data-title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
```

Comment: No prob. Pls mark as answer if it worked for u. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dude, Model popup coming when i click first row of the table but if i click second thrid its not coming. my table row dynamically it will generate how to get based on ID? can you help me?

Comment: Dude, i have update working code. which is you send that one. modelpopup window is coming action method also called successfully but only problem is user_id its coming null. my user id is string example: sena023.

Comment: Remove parseInt from delete url in ajax. Updated answer.

Comment: i have added my controller code. everything working fine. when i checked alert(userId) it coming selected row userId. only problem is action method i'm getting null value. once i deleted i have to reload the page and should show the successfully message to the user. i have modified my ajax code like that.     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
            url: '/Admin/deleteUser/',
            data: JSON.stringify(userId),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {

Comment: Pls post your controller action method for delete. And about reload page and success message pls work it out yourself. Here, I can't do all code for you. Makes sense?

Comment: dude, already i have added my controller action method. can you check please

Comment: Wow! awesome! its working successfully. and i want to learn ajax scripts do you know any sites? when i checked lot of sites is there i'm not able to find proper one. once again thank you very much for quick update.

Comment: Pls mark as answer. Regarding ajax there are many posts here in stackoverflow read questions and answers and TRY OUT yourself to learn more. Happy coding!

Comment: @SENA Don't you to mark answers when someone takes out time to help you here?

Comment: Friend, This problem is solved how to close this one?

Comment: You need to click Tick sign to my answer. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) about what you should do once question is answered.